# Is this a C language undefined behaviour? Different results in clang and GCC

Tags: c, gcc, clang, side-effects, unspecified-behavior

I'm getting different results for the same code with different compilers. Is this a undefined behaivour?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int a;
int b=10;
int puan_ekle(int puan, int bonus){
    puan=puan+bonus;
    a=puan-5;
    bonus--;
    return bonus;
}
int main(){
    a=23;
    printf("Result1 %d \n", a);
    a=a+puan_ekle(a,b);
    printf("Result2 %d \n", a);
    a=a+puan_ekle(a,b);
    printf("Result3 %d \n", a);
}
```

Comment: I can confirm different results with Clang (x86-64 9.0) and GCC (x86-64 9.2). I believe you are indeed dealing with behavior that is undefined in C with respect to the order of evaluation of operand expressions with statements like `a = a + f(a)` where `f` modifies `a`. Different compilers are thus free to do what they want in these kind of cases. This one in particular is related to something called *sequence points*, I believe, but I haven't drawn my conclusions yet, hence no answer from me (yet). Just wanted to give you a helpful comment though.

Comment: I suspect it's *unspecified*, not *undefined*.  (But I'm not certain.)  It is certainly not well-defined.

Comment: @SteveSummit I stand corrected, I am much too vague with these terms (it has been a while I've had my nose in a C standards document), which evidently have different meanings with C. I should have written "unspecified", not "undefined".

Comment: Is this really the most minimal [mcve] that repros the problem?  It would be a better question if you at least used English var names, and explained in the question (and title) what's weird about this code.  (global a and `a + f(a)` where `f` also modifies `a`.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The behavior is unspecified, not undefined.

The C standard distinguishes these. C 2018 3.4.4 1 says:

> **unspecified behavior**
>
> behavior, that results from the use of an unspecified value, or other behavior upon which this document provides two or more possibilities and imposes no further requirements on which is chosen in any instance

And 3.4.3 1 says:

> **undefined behavior**
>
> behavior, upon use of a nonportable or erroneous program construct or of erroneous data, for which this document imposes no requirements

In some situations, when an object is both used for its value and modified, a rule in the C standard makes the behavior undefined. 6.5 2 says:

> If a side effect on a scalar object is unsequenced relative to either a different side effect on the same scalar object or a value computation using the value of the same scalar object, the behavior is undefined. If there are multiple allowable orderings of the subexpressions of an expression, the behavior is undefined if such an unsequenced side effect occurs in any of the orderings.

Let’s see how this applies to `a=a+puan_ekle(a,b);`. In this expression:

1. `a` is modified by the `a=`.
2. `a` is used in the `a+`.
3. `a` is used in the arguments `(a,b)`.
4. Inside the function `puan_ekle`, `a` is modified with `a=puan-5;`.

The modifications are side effects—they are something that happens separately from computing the value of the expression. If either of the modifications, 1 or 4, is unsequenced relative to any of the other items, the behavior is undefined.

Regarding 1, 6.5.16 3 says:

> … The side effect of updating the stored value of the left operand is sequenced after the value computations of the left and right operands…

So 1 is sequenced after 2 and 3. Since 4 is a side effect, not a value computation, we still have to consider the relationship of 1 and 4. To resolve this, we will consider sequence points. Per 5.1.2.3, “The presence of a sequence point between the evaluation of expressions *A* and *B* implies that every value computation and side effect associated with *A* is sequenced before every value computation and side effect associated with *B*.”

Next we need to know what a *full expression* is and that there is a sequence point after each full expression. 6.8 4 says:

> A *full expression* is an expression that is not part of another expression, nor part of a declarator or abstract declarator… There is a sequence point between the evaluation of a full expression and the evaluation of the next full expression to be evaluated.

This means that every statement inside `puan_ekle` is or contains a full expression: `puan=puan+bonus` is a full expression, `a=puan-5` is a full expression, `bonus--` is a full expression, and the `bonus` in `return bonus` is a full expression. So, after `a=puan-5`, there is a sequence point.

Since, for `a=`, the side effect of modifying `a` is sequenced after the value computations of the operands. Evaluating those operands includes calling the function, which includes its sequence points. So effect 4, modifying `a` in `a=puan-5;`, must be completed before execution continues to the next statement, and hence must be completed before effect 1. So 1 and 4 are sequenced.

What is left is to consider effect 4 with respect to 2 and 3. 4 is sequenced after 3 because a function call is sequenced after evaluation of its arguments, per 6.5.2.2 10:

> There is a sequence point after the evaluations of the function designator and the actual arguments but before the actual call…

Now all we have left is the sequencing of 2 relative to 4. In this, there is no specification of which is first. The evaluations of the operands of `+` are unsequenced, so, for `a+puan_ekle(a,b)`, a C implementation may do either `a` first or `puan_ekle(a,b)` first. However, whichever it does first, there is a sequence point between 2 and 4:

- If `a` is evaluated first, then, before the function call, there is a sequence point (per 6.5.2.2 10, quoted above).
- If `puan_ekle(a,b)` is evaluated first, there is a sequence point after the full expression `a=puan-5`.

Thus, 2 and 4 are *indeterminately sequenced*. (5.1.2.3 3: “… Evaluations *A* and *B* are indeterminately sequenced when *A* is sequenced either before or after *B*, but it is unspecified which…”) But they are not unsequenced, so there is no undefined behavior. The behavior is unspecified because there are two possibilities. The C implementation is required implement one of those two possibilities, which is different from undefined behavior, in which there would be no requirements.

Comment: Thank you for detailed answer. I can understand it more clearly now.  But,  a=puan_ekle(a,b)+a;  changing the order like this changes the result with clang but not with GCC why?

Comment: It is unspecified what happens, @lotusexpeditor, so both compilers are behaving correctly.

Answer (score 3):

The order pf evaluation of the operands of an additive operator is unspecified.

So for example in this statement

```
a=a+puan_ekle(a,b);
```

one compiler can at first evaluate the value of a and then call the function puan_ekle(a,b) that has a side effect of changing a. While other compiler can at first call the function and after that get the value of a after it was changed in the function.

So the program has undefined behavior.

If the function had no the side effect then the behavior would be well-defined independently of the order of evaluation of operands of the additive operator.

Comment: How can I prove that this is undefined? That was my exam question and my instructor believes that it's defined. I looked at the standards document but can't find anything sufficient to prove.

Comment: @lotusexpeditor Make a refer to the unspecified order of evaluation of operands of an additive operator.

Comment: There is a big difference between *unspecified* (either order is allowed, but it must be one or the other) and *undefined behavior* (could cause demons to fly out of your nose).  Which is it, and why?

Comment: @NateEldredge The result is undefined.

Comment: @NateEldredge For example the function can not have a side effect. In this case the order of evaluation of operands as usual is unspecified but the result is defined independently of the order of evaluation.

Comment: What makes the behavior undefined? The C standard permits indeterminate sequencing that is not, by itself, undefined behavior.

Comment: Specifically, the rule in C 2018 6.5 2 that says the behavior is undefined if a side effect on a scalar object is **unsequenced** relative to a different side effect or a value computation on the same object. In `a+puan_ekle(a,b)`, there are sequence points just before the call and in the full expressions in the function. The function may be called before or after the `a` left of the `+` is evaluated, but, in either case, there is sequencing. So the side effects and value computations of `a` are **indeterminately sequenced**, not unsequenced. Where is the undefined behavior?

Comment: Why would a compiler choose to evaluate `a` before the function call which is clearly not the logical behavior to most readers ? What is the significance of that decision ?

Comment: @SyedAhmedJamil Do you mean, in something like `a + f()`, why would a compiler choose to evaluate `a` before `f()`? Two reasons: (1) Left-to-right evaluation is pretty common. (2) Optimizing compilers have all sorts of inscrutable reasons for evaluating things in one order or another, and in C, at least, they're free to act on those reasons, since they're under no obligation whatsoever to pick "the logical behavior to most readers" or anything like that.